# Distributing $N$ distinct objects in $R$ distinct boxes when order matters

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $P(r+n-1,r-1)$ ways to distribute $n$ objects in $r$ boxes when the order of objects in each box matters. I tried to find out why but I failed.

when the order of objects in each box doesn't matter it equals to $r^n$ because there are $r$ choices for every object and since there are $n$ objects it becomes $r^n$ . But I can't solve this problem when the order of objects in the boxes matter.

---

**UPDATE**:

> $P(n,r) = n!/(n-r)!$

Comment: What do you mean by $P(r+n-1, r-1)$ ? Binomial coefficient ?

Comment: @WLOG I updated the question and defined the $P(n,r)$

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $P(n,r) = n!/r!(n-r)!$ ?  With your current definition, you don't get the right answer for $n=1$.  If there is only one object, there are clearly $r$ ways to put that object in $r$ boxes (the order is irrelevant here).

Comment: @AlistairSavage No I'm sure the formula is right. it is in Grimaldi discrete math book

Comment: @RossMillikan: Doesn't it give $P(r,r-1) = r!/1!=r!$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of the boxes as bins arranged in a straight line, separated by walls.  You can place the first object in any bin, giving you $r$ choices.  But now that object has split its bin in two: another object can be placed *before* it or *after* it in its bin.  So you have $r+1$ choices for the second object.  Similarly you have $r+2$ choices for the third object, etc.  This gives $r(r+1)\cdots(r+n-1) = (r+n-1)!/(r-1)!$ possibilities.

Comment: This gives $P(r+n-1,n)$, which I agree with.

Answer (score 3):

The combinatorial species in question is
$$\mathfrak{S}_{=r}(\mathfrak{S}(\mathcal{Z})).$$
This gives the generating function
$$\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^r
= \frac{1}{(1-z)^r}.$$
Extracting coefficients we get
$$n! [z^n] \frac{1}{(1-z)^r}.$$
Apply the Newton binomial to solve this, getting
$$n! {n+r-1\choose r-1}
= \frac{(n+r-1)!}{(r-1)!}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Place a fixed wall at either end. The remaining things, $n$ objects and $r-1$ walls, can be placed in any order inside the fixed walls, and each arrangement of those $n+r-1$ things gives a different assignment of balls to bins. The walls are interchangeable while the balls are not, so the number of arrangements is $\frac{(n+r-1)!}{(r-1)!}$.